# Do not allow users to access any other webpage than index.php (through .htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I just hosted my first website project.

The `index.php` is located in the **document root**. All other (subordinated) `.php` pages are located in a subfolder called `/pages`; `HTML` pages are located in `/include`; `javaScript` pages in `/scripts` etc.

I want to forbid the DIRECT (url) access to any subordinated page of my website.

What should I add to my .htaccess file in order that only index.php OR index.html in the Document Root can be accessible from the Internet through an url, but **NOT** any other .php or .html page ?

By any other page I mean a page like `www.mydomain.com/pages/somepage.php`.

I can create my own `.htaccess` in my document root page - as a matter of fact, I have already done it for some other purposes, so I could enforce the above by adding to this file.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html#deny

Comment: @CBroe From Apache: **Deny Directive - Controls which hosts are denied access to the server**. I don't want to deny access to my website from a specific host. I want to control what page is DIRECTLY accessible in the folder structure below my document root via weblink, and which is not.

Comment: Sorry, what you wanted was kinda unclear until you commented on Starkeen's answer. Yes, if you want that people have to visit your index page _first_, before they can access other pages, then you will have to implement that via a cookie or session.

Comment: Thanks. I've seen this question asked in several places on the Internet, but no .htaccess solution.

Comment: There can't be one, because HTTP is a [stateless protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol).

Comment: I don't know much (!) about Internet protocols, but I **vaguely** remember reading recently that https is not stateless. Would that change anything ? Just asking.

Comment: HTTPS is just HTTP over TLS, that doesn’t change anything about its stateless nature. // You _could_ use .htaccess/mod_rewrite to _add_ state via a cookie (RewriteCond can check cookies send by the client, RewriteRule can set cookies) - but that might be a bit complex; implementing it in PHP via session is easier.

Comment: I am trying to do that just now - the downside is, it needs updating all my website's pages.

Answer (score 0):

To block all .php and .html requests except **index.html** and **index.php** , put the following rule at the top of your .htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php|index\html).+\html|php)$ - [F]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^/(index\.html|index\.php)$
RewriteRule ^.+\.(php|html) - [F]
```

Comment: But will I still be able to access my other .php files ?

Comment: @Mikey This blocks access for everyone.

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I need. I want people to be able to access all the webpages of the site, just not directly through a 'shorcut' url. Maybe I should set a $_SESSION variable in the **main page** and check it afterwards in all the other pages.